# Google BigQuery - Get unique rows based on one column

Tags: google-bigquery

Have this BigQuery

```
select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.clone_url") AS clone_url, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.language") AS language, integer(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.stargazers_count")) as stars from githubarchive:day.20200115 where  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.language")="C" group by language,clone_url,stars order by stars DESC limit 1000;
```

It return several entries for "clone_url" with unique "stars".

How do can I show only highest starcount unique for clone_url?

Can this query be optimized?

Below are query results:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you still using BigQuery Legacy SQL - so below is for Legacy SQL

```
#legacySQL 
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.clone_url") AS clone_url, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.language") AS language, 
  MAX(INTEGER(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.stargazers_count"))) AS stars 
FROM [githubarchive:day.20200115]
WHERE  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.language")="C" 
GROUP BY language, clone_url 
ORDER BY stars DESC 
LIMIT 1000
```

Please note: it is highly recommended to migrate to BigQuery Standard SQL, so above would looks as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.clone_url") AS clone_url, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.language") AS language, 
  MAX(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.stargazers_count") AS INT64)) AS stars 
FROM `githubarchive.day.20200115`
WHERE  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.pull_request.base.repo.language")="C" 
GROUP BY language, clone_url 
ORDER BY stars DESC 
LIMIT 1000
```

Both above queries will return something like below

[image]